# Is it possible to know when an ajax call has been completed in OOP approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

Sorry for the confusing title. I was at loss of words to describe it in a better manner.

So this is what is I'm trying to find out. Let's say

```
function myClass()
{
   $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:'some/path/',
      success:function(response)
      {
         // call has been compeleted, set some flag here
      }
   });

   return this;
}

var obj = new myClass();
jQuery('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>'); // so now the user will know he has to wait for some operation to be completed...    

// now determine on this line whether the Ajax call is still in progress
while(<ajax call still in progress>)
{
   // i do not need to do anything here since the overlay is already there in place
}

// now this is where I want to remove the overlay
jQuery('#overlay').remove();
```

### UPDATE

Basically, I'm showing a loading overlay when the ajax call is made and once it finishes, I would like to remove that overlay. ***I know I can write the code inside the class itself, but I want the control of adding/removing the overlay outside the class.***

Comment: @asprin Use `beforeSend` and `complete` events to start and stop _doing something_ while request is in progress.

Comment: It is important to know what exactly you want to do while the call is in progress. Can you be specific?

Comment: You are not supposed to return anything in constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the promise nature of such a request. So keep a reference to what 
`$.ajax` returns in a property of your created object.

You can then use the `then` method on that property to know when all is done.

Here is code making a call to a test server which shows a silver overlay while the request is pending (1 second):

```js
function myClass(path) {
   this.request = $.ajax({
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      type: 'get',
      url: path,
   });
}

var obj = new myClass('https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=1000');
jQuery('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>');

obj.request.then(function(response) {
    console.log('done');
     jQuery('#overlay').remove();
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any attempt to make such code synchronous is bad practice. You need to embrace the asynchronous nature of Ajax calls, and use a callback system, like available through promises.

Comment: Well, I had removed all the irrelevant code from the class `myClass`. I can't use `return` for the ajax call because I'm already returning `this` at the end of the class.

Comment: I updated my answer to the latest version of your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's great to see how one problem can be solved in many ways. It's gotta be difficult for me to choose only one as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```js
/* The constructor. */
function myClass(successCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    context: this,
    type: "get",
    url: "some/path/",
    success: function(response) {
      this.inProgress = false;
      successCallback.call(this);
    }
  });

  this.inProgress = true;
}

/* Create a new class and add an overlay to the body. */
var obj = new myClass(removeOverlay);
jQuery('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>');

/* The function that removes the overlay. */
function removeOverlay () {
  if (!this.inProgress) jQuery('#overlay').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's great to see how one problem can be solved in many ways. It's gotta be difficult for me to choose only one as accepted answer.

Comment: You're welcome @asprin. I'm glad I could help you. Choose the one that helps you the most. No hard feelings 

Answer (score 1):

You can pass callbacks as parameters to your object constructor:

```
function myClass(onStart, onStop) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'some/path',
        data: {
            action: 'test'
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            if (onStart && typeof onStart == 'function') {
                onStart();
            }
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //do something
        },
        complete: function() {
            if (onStop && typeof onStop == 'function') {
                onStop();
            }
        }
    });
}

var onStart = function () {
    console.log('Started');
}
var onStop = function () {
    console.log('Stopped');
}

var obj = new myClass(onStart, onStop);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's great to see how one problem can be solved in many ways. It's gotta be difficult for me to choose only one as accepted answer.